# Where can I find the StreamedTextArea() class - is it deprecated?

Tags: java, .net

javac cannot find this class : StreamedTextArea() which I assumed was part of java.awt.*. If I need to write it myself then can anyone offer me some advice. The only references to it online were from ~1999 which inclines me to think it is not a Sun class but one I must write myself. Also in this code (which is from a textbook) they use Frame instead of JFrame. Is this deprecated, how should this application be written nowadays ? Please I have tried finding the answers myself online but to no avail.

The application :

```
//URLViewer.java
//This is a simple application that provides a window in which you can view the
//contents of a URL.

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;



public class URLViewer extends Frame implements WindowListener, ActionListener  {

  TextField theURL = new TextField();
  Button loadbutton = new Button("load");
  StreamedTextArea theDisplay = new StreamedTextArea();

                public URLViewer()  {
                  super ("URL Viewer");
                }

                                public void init()  {

                                this.add("North", theURL);
                                this.add("Center", theDisplay);
                                Panel south = new Panel();
                                south.add(loadbutton);
                                this.add("South", south);
                                theURL.addActionListener(this);
                                this.addWindowListener(this);
                                this.setLocation(50, 50);
                                this.pack();
                                this.show();
                                }

        public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent evt)  {

          try  {
          URL u = new URL (theURL.getText());
          InputStream in = u.openStream();
          OutputStream out = theDisplay.getOutputStream();
          StreamCopier.copy(in, out);
          in.close();
          out.close();
          }  catch (MalformedURLException ex)  {theDisplay.setText("Invalid URL");}
             catch (IOException ex)  {theDisplay.setText("Invalid URL");}
        }


        public void windowClosing (WindowEvent e)  {         
        this.setVisible(false);
        this.dispose();
        }
                                public void windowOpened(WindowEvent e) {}
                                public void windowClosed(WindowEvent e) {}
                                public void windowIconified(WindowEvent e) {}
                                public void windowDeiconified(WindowEvent e) {}
                                public void windowActivated(WindowEvent e) {}
                                public void windowDeactivated(WindowEvent e) {}


        public static void main (String[] args)  {

          URLViewer me = new URLViewer();
          me.init();
        }

}
```

And StreamCopier :

```
import java.io.*;

public class StreamCopier  {

  public static void main (String[] args)  {

                try  {

                copy (null, null);

                } catch (IOException e) {System.err.println(e);}
  }

  public static void copy (InputStream in, OutputStream out) throws IOException  {

    //do not allow other threads to read from the  input or
    //write to the output while copying is taking place.
    synchronized (in)  {
      synchronized (out)  {
        byte [] buffer = new byte [256];
                                  while (true)   {
                                    int bytesRead = in.read(buffer);
                                    if (bytesRead == -1) break;
                                    out.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                                  }
      }
    }
  }  //end copy()

}
```

Comment: You state, `"javac cannot find this class : StreamedTextArea() which I assumed was part of java.awt.*"` -- Rather than making this assumption, don't assume, since a quick look at the Java API will tell you that it's not, and so that is the first place you should go for this type of question. Since you found this code in a book or online, I suppose the code for this class may be in this book or online as well.

Comment: Note that Frame is a component from the AWT GUI library, and while not technically deprecated, you should no longer use it or AWT components since the AWT libray is over 14 years out of date. Use either Swing or JavaFx.

Comment: Because StreamedTextArea() sounds GUI-related. I've just checked and no it isn't there.

Comment: Again, the API is the final arbiter of what is or is not included in the core Java libraries. This is a great resource to learn to use well and to love.

Comment: I'm sure it is. Please tell me if StreamedTextArea is a part of it ? I literally cant find it anywhere.

Comment: Actually you already have your answer in your own comment above. You can't find it in the API, and so it does not exist as part of the core Java libraries.

Comment: Ok I found it earlier in the book :redface. Thank you Hovercraft.

Comment: Glad you've got it working. I imagine that it would need some sort of inner buffer and would concern itself with handling the streaming of data in a background thread that did not block the GUI's event thread.

Comment: That code is so old I would not use it. In addition to NOT use AWT components you should NOT be using the `show()` method. You should NOT be using `this.add("South", south);`. That is don't use hardcoded literal strings as a constraint, the API has field values for you to use also the constraint should be used as the second parameter, not the first.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://linux3.dti.supsi.ch/~lepori/Java/Jfiles/IO/StreamedTextArea.java) is StreamedTextArea.java.  I found it on [this page](http://linux3.dti.supsi.ch/~lepori/Java/Jfiles/IO/), which also has code that matches your StreamCopier class.  [This page](http://linux3.dti.supsi.ch/~lepori/Java/Jfiles/IO/IO.html) also contains information on that site.